# Why does String have a prototype.length property as well as generate a direct length property on instances of String

Tags: javascript

Why does `String` have a `prototype.length` as well as clearly generate a **direct** length property (that must’ve come from somewhere in the `String` constructor function)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how it is. From the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-properties-of-the-string-prototype-object):

> The String prototype object:
>
> - is a [String exotic object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#string-exotic-object) and has the internal methods specified for such objects.
> - has a [[StringData]] internal slot whose value is the empty String.
> - has a `length` property whose initial value is `0` and whose attributes are { [[Writable]]: `false`, [[Enumerable]]: `false`,
>   [[Configurable]]: `false` }.

This might be considered an accident or not, but it's too late to change now. See also [Why is Boolean.prototype a Boolean object again? (And same for String and Number, but not Date or RegExp?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50614565/1048572).